# Solr - How to get Term Vector Information on Distributed Search

Tags: solr

I am using distributed query to fetch records. Distributed Search Document on wiki says , Distributed Search support Term Vector. but I m getting error while querying. Not sure if I am doing anything wrong.

below is my Query to fetch Term Vector with Distributed Search.

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/core1/tvrh?q=id:3426545&tv.all=true&f.text.tv.tf_idf=false&f.text.tv.df=false&tv.fl=text&shards=localhost:8080/solr/core1,localhost:8080/solr/core2,localhost:8080/solr/core3&shards.qt=select&debugQuery=on
```

Below is error coming...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.TermVectorComponent.finishStage(TermVectorComponent.java:437)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:317)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:242)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1817)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:639)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Could you specify which version are you getting this error and have you created the index in a different version?

Comment: @Junaid, I am using Solr4.2

Comment: There is a JIRA issue regarding this but reported for version 4.1. Also one of the users had the same issue, he was using 4.2 but the index was created in 4.1.